# With SSH on Windows, how can I provide access to just a single folder?

Tags: windows, ssh

**Goal**

I have an SSH server enabled on my Windows machine and would like to provide access such that in a clean manner only one folder is accessible (in this case `C:\SSHShare`).

**Initial Ideas**

The initial thought that I had was to to create a local user (say `SSHUser`) without admin privileges, and then give this user access to the `C:\SSHShare`. However in doing so they would get access to `C:\Users\SSHUser\*\**` and possibly other locations on the filesystem.

I could possibly find a way to remove access to this folder in `C:\Users` and other places if necessary, but even if I was successful in that, it feels like I'm working against the Windows system by creating a user and removing access to its own user folder, which could have unforeseen consequences.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What _kind_ of access exactly? Do you want to provide SFTP, or do you want interactive terminal?

Comment: That's a good point, I should have explicitly mentioned that I'm looking for SFTP access. I thought the set of folders accessible via a shell would be the same visible through SFTP, is that not the case?

Comment: Not necessarily... The shell is its own program and stuff you run from it is also standalone programs; on Windows there _isn't_ a "chroot" function which could contain it to a folder, and even on Linux/BSD (which have one) it would be useless because you couldn't run any programs at all, you'd have a shell that accepts no commands. Whereas the SFTP service is all-in-one and could simply be told to refuse bad requests.

Comment: However, I haven't looked into whether OpenSSH's configuration for doing so is actually cross-platform or whether it depends on chroot... Does your case require the Windows built-in OpenSSH or would any other SFTP-capable SSH server work as well?

Comment: Other options could work, sure. I just chose the inbuilt Windows one of convenience.